# Correct OmniThread abstraction for a a multi-stage process

Tags: multithreading, delphi, omnithreadlibrary

I have a sort of complex multi stage process that needs to do the following stages in the background (I am using OmniThreadLibrary) for a document, first in the main thread I create the object (interfaced object) in which I need to perform several stages.

Once the object is created in the main thread the user sent to a processing queue (this is where I send it to a [OmniThread Pipeline](http://otl.17slon.com/book/doku.php?id=book%3ahighlevel%3apipeline)) and perform the following stages:

1. **Stage 1)** Perform some "expensive" calculations on this document (locally) and save it to a database (using IBObjects, I create my own DB connection in this stage)
2. **Stage 2)** Send this document to a WebService which performs some other calculations to it, save the result to the database (I am ensuring of calling CoInitialize/CoUninitialize) <- This stage can fail due to internet timeouts, web service errors, web service maintenance windows, etc. need to handle those.
3. **Stage 3)** Generate a PDF file of this document (using FastReports) and save it to disk.
4. **Stage 4)** Optional - Send this document by email. <- This also can fail fue to internet timeouts, other errors, etc.

From all the OmniThreadLibrary abstractions (high & low) is the Pipeline the best abstraction for this particular problem? Or should I just program the queue and stages using a Low Level abstraction?

**Other concerns:**

- I need it to be a FIFO queue.
- ¿How to handle exceptions (and retries) in stages 2 and 4?
- ¿Is it a good idea to create the object in the main thread or should I instantiate the database object in each stage and free it from memory?
- ¿Should I use a Lock when performing the database updates?
- The Pipeline abstraction needs to know when I am done "Adding items", however during my application lifespan the user could add from one to hundreds of documents so I can never call "CompleteAdding" or ¿should I create a new pipeline for each document to process?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why the 4 stages can't just be executed in a single "task"? I have often found in these sort of things that while there is a logical break the stage behavior there is no reason why the code can just execute in a single flow. So you could create a single task that calls 4 sub-procs and can handle the necessary retries/exceptions/etc. If that is an option then either a normal low level omnithread thread object or a omnithread background worker could be used.

Comment: Thanks @Graymatter it could be a possibility, haven't really thought I could use a Omnithread background worker using a single task. Will do an experiment with it.

Comment: For your other concern. I would definitely create the database connection and other objects in the thread and free them afterwards. You can use a pool and retrieve them from the pool but they are not thread safe so you will need to be careful.

Comment: I don't think the pipeline will help you in this case. Because of this **long term** stages and storing results to DB, how will you recover the current job stage after a system restart?

Comment: Thanks again @Graymatter, It looks simpler just doing every stage in the processing procedure of the worker. Will update with my progress.

Comment: @SirRufo yes actually one my concerns was that. Now I am taking the approach of using one Omnithread Background Worker and doing all the stages in a single procedure. In case of a system restart I will just send the document trough this process again and ignore the stages already performed successfully.

Comment: Just store the job, the desired stages and which of them are completed (in DB, File, etc.). Build a scheduler that will start the next stage of the job reading the job store and you should be fine

Comment: Pipeline might  be executed in a pool of threads,  that mean either you will use IBO connection outside the thread created it, or you would have to create connection in each procedure call of stage1. Latter is slow. Former Is not typical mode. Can IBO handle it? Maybe UIB is better?